# What is Container And Wrapper in web development?

Tags: html, css

Like what container do if I used it on div tag and what will wrapper do if I used it on div tag or what is the different between them.

Answer (score 1):

Container and wrapper are the same thing - they are classes usually applied to divs that contain other elements (or wrap around them). The only differernce is that in Bootsatrap - .container has specific styling applied to it - but the concept is that they are both just classes that are applied to elements and not just to divs either -could be any element that houses other elements.

As can be seen in the snuippet - they are exactly the same.

I personally use .wrapper more than container due to the Bootstrap connotations and I like the idea tht a div wraps around the inner contents - but that is person preference only.

```css
.container,
.wrapper {
 border: solid 1px red;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 margin: 16px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p> I am a p element within a div with a class of container</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p> I am a p element within a div with a class of wrapper</p>
</div>
```

Comment: *As can be seen in the snuippet - they are exactly the same.* --> because *you* made them the same. This is purely opinion based, there is nothing in CSS called container or wrapper

Comment: That was my point - a div with two classes that have the same styling - have the same outcome. The point was that there is no semantic difference between div.container and div.wrapper... as distinguished from say - a div and a span... both are non specific container elements -that can house other content - but the difference between them is that the div is a block level element and the span is an inline-level eleemnt. - or in other words there is a difference between them. A div with either container class or wrapper class is the same... unless you count the bootstrap styling on div.container.